# How can I use different hrefs in my fancybox call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I have the following fancybox call:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
            'closeClick'  : false,
            'scrolling'   : 'no',
             afterShow: function(){
            //do some stuff  
             }
        });
    });
```

for influence on the following:

```
<a href="example_url" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"><img src="example"/></a>
```

what I would like to do is add the href to the fancybox call so that I can simply put a hash tag in the href in the html.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
            'closeClick'  : false,
            'scrolling'   : 'no',
                'href'        : 'example_url',
             afterShow: function(){
            //do some stuff  
             }
        });
    });
```

But I need to take it a bit further. Lets say I have three different items to consider:

```
<a href="#" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"><img src="example"/></a> //requires url-1
<a href="#" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"><img src="example"/></a> //requires url-2
<a href="#" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"><img src="example"/></a> //requires url-3
```

I know I need to give each one some type of unique identifier. Further, I realize I could just make three different fancybox calls for each one, but I think the better way to do it would be something like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
                //do some processing here to find out what triggered the fancybox, then set a variable with the proper href based on that input. Could have a switch statement etc
            'closeClick'  : false,
            'scrolling'   : 'no',
                'href'        : //variable holding proper url
             afterShow: function(){
            //do some stuff  
             }
        });
    });
```

But I am having trouble making it actually happen how I envision!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I should say that my example is using Fancybox 2, it will probably not work in the earlier versions

You can have the links carry a data-href attribute, which you can use in the fancybox call like this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xEtZ8/)

```
<a class="fancybox" data-href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/YtwCt/show/" href="#">URL 1</a>

<a class="fancybox" data-href="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html" href="#">URL 2</a>
```

And JS

```
$(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        beforeLoad: function() {
            this.href = this.element.data('href');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I like this answer but I would like to know if there is a way to do it just in the JS also.

Comment: If you don't have the URL stored in the HTML elements, how will you then differentiate them?

Comment: class, name, id, anything really I would think? Then in the javascript I could pick the proper url based on that unique identifier? That is what I have in mind anyways.

Comment: Sure that is possible, I personally like the suggested one better, but the possibilities are limitless. Something fitting what you describe could be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bUj7L/1/

Comment: Outstanding...you have given me two excellent options. Thanks!

Comment: If using fancybox 2, you can use `data-fancybox-href` instead, then you don't need to add the `beforeLoad` callback at all. see updated http://jsfiddle.net/xEtZ8/1/